# HTTP GET: send links of children and parent of the requested directory

Tags: html, c, http, directory

I am handling HTTP GET requests, and what I'm trying to do is as follows:

If the request corresponds to a directory and the directory does not contain an index.html
file, respond with an HTML page containing links to all of the immediate children of the
directory (similar to ls -1), as well as a link to the parent directory. (A link to the
parent directory looks like Parent directory)

note1: To list the contents of a directory, I use opendir() and readdir(). Note2:
– Links in HTTP can use relative paths or absolute paths.

It is not working. Two error examples are as follows:

FAIL-1 Get the directory listing of the root:
    I sent an HTTP request to the server, and I got back some HTML.
    I looked for a link to '/test_directory1', but I could not find it.
    (Note: Links containing relative paths in the HTML were resolved relative to '/'.)
    However, I did find a link to '/test_file.txt'.
    How to reproduce:
        I created an empty directory and put a test_file.txt file and a test_directory1 inside it.
        I started ./httpserver with the --files option.
        I sent a HTTP request for / to the web server, in order to see all the files I created.

FAIL-2 Get the directory listing of a subdirectory:
    I sent an HTTP request to the server, and I got back some HTML.
    I looked for a link to '/test_directory1', but I could not find it.
    (Note: Links containing relative paths in the HTML were resolved relative to '/test_directory1/test_directory2/'.)
    However, I did find a link to '/test_directory1/test_directory2'.
    How to reproduce:
        I created an empty directory and put a test_directory1 directory inside of it.
        Then I put a test_directory2 inside test_directory1.
        Then I started ./httpserver with the --files option.
        I sent a HTTP request for /test_directory1/test_directory2 (with NO slash at the end of the path.
        I look for a list of files inside test_directory2, which should include a link to the parent directory (/test_directory1/).

```
/*if is directory but doesn't contain index.html, send links instead*/
  struct dirent *dp;
  http_start_response(fd, 200);
  http_send_header(fd, "Content-Type", "text/html");

  http_end_headers(fd);
  while( (dp = readdir(opendir(fullPath)))!= NULL){

    char * filename = malloc(256+1);
    strcpy(filename, dp -> d_name);
    char * linkString = malloc(256+256+18+1);
    strcpy(linkString, "<<a href=\"");
    strcat(linkString, filename);
    strcat(linkString, "\">");
    strcat(linkString, filename);
    strcat(linkString, "</a></");
    http_send_string(fd, linkString);
    free(filename);

    printf("Is directory but doesn't have index.html, so all links %s\n", linkString);
    free(linkString);

  }

  http_send_string(fd, "<html><a href=\"../\">Parent directory</a><html>");
```

Comment: why do you do the printf inside of the loop ? also why build the string when it would be safer to just print the tag directly to the stream, It also seems like the proper way to print the output is `http_send_string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry to say this but your code seems wrong on so many level :

- the while condition would be evaluated at every loop, meaning your directory **will be open every time** until it cannot be opened anymore.

  Write this instead :

  ```
  if ((dir = opendir (fullPath)) == NULL) {
      //error handling
  }
  while ((dp = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
      // print tag here
  }
  ```
- you are building the tag wrong, your output would be

  ```
  <<a href="filename">filename</a>>
  ```

  which I don't really know what different browser would display in that case
- try to avoid dynamic memory allocation unless needed, and you don't need it there ( plus check if the malloc result is not null, if malloc fail for whatever reason )

  ```
  // print each tag
  const char* const filename=dp -> d_name;
  http_send_string( fd, "<a href=\"" ); // start tag open 
  http_send_string( fd, filename ); // attribute value
  http_send_string( fd, "\">" ); // close start tag
  http_send_string( fd, filename ); // tag inner text 
  http_send_string( fd, "</a></br>" ); // closing tag ( with a line break )
  ```
- *Preferably* : put the link to the parent directory on top of the page ( that is before your print loop )

Comment: This is honesty the best answer I have ever seen. Thanks!! This solved my problem and my code works now.